# phpExcel - Excel found unreadable content when use formula?

Tags: formula, phpexcel

I wrote this code but when I open excel file I had error "Excel found unreadable content". Here is my code

```
$i=8
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$i,'=D.$i*E.$i');
$i++;
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is single quotes (`'`), which means PHP won't interpolate variables inside the [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), and you're not breaking out of the string for concatenation.

Use double quotes (`"`) without trying to concatenate:

```
"=D{$i}*E{$i}"
```

or concatenate:

```
'=D'.$i.'*E.'$i
```